# Flatten Parent child collection using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I need to flatten my parent child collection in mongodb . This is similar to question asked for sql at :

[Flatten parent child hierarchy with multiple parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430157/flatten-parent-child-hierarchy-with-multiple-parents)

my collection is like 
category: {_id, type, name, parent:(mapped to self i.e. category collection) )}

And the current depth of child is 3 with type L1, L2,L3

Result will be with fields: (L1_id, L1_name, L2_id, L2_name, L3_id, L3_name)

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mongodb aggregation pipeline` to achieve the same. More specifically you can use `$lookup` twice to populate `parent` and its `parent`, and finally `$project` to flatten the structure.

Try this:

```
Category.aggregation([{
    $lookup : {
        from :"categories",
        localField : "parent",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as  :"parent"
    }
},{
    $unwind : "$parent"
},{
    $lookup : {
        from :"categories",
        localField : "parent.parent",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as  :"parent.parent"
    }
},{
    $unwind : "$parent.parent"
},{
    $project : {
        l1_id  : "$_id",
        l1_name : "$name",
        l2_id : "$parent._id", 
        l2_name : "$parent.name" ,
        l3_id : "$parent.parent._id", 
        l2_name : "$parent.parent.name" 
    }
}]).then(result => {
    // result will have l1_id, l1_name, l2_id, l2_name, l3_id, l3_name
    // where l2 is the parent,
    // and l3 is the parent of parent 
}).
```

**Note:** `$unwind` is used after `$lookup` stage, as `$lookup` returns an array, we need to unwind it to convert it to object.

For more info please read [Mongodb $lookup documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/),and [$project documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

i hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Multiple lookup and unwind worked very well. Only thing is that the output. I did a small change. Actually, the first lookup ends up as l3 and then l2 and last as l1 ... So, project; {..... } label need to be reversed.